# Swift 4 authencation for email/password

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift4

I am trying to make a social media app like Instragram.

Here is my button function

```
if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                // Create account
            } else {
                KeychainWrapper.standard.set((user?.uid)!, forKey: "KEY_UID")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFeed", sender: nil)
            }
        }
```

I have already import firebase to appdelegate.

But I am still getting a error `Use of unresolved identifier 'Auth'`

Comment: You should import firebase in this viewcontroller also

Comment: I have imported firebase and added pod 'Firebase/Auth' still not working

Comment: I have it on sign it button

Answer (score 1):

Include in your pod file

> pod 'Firebase/Auth'

Import

> import Firebase

Comment: Questions asking for clarification or more information should be posted as comments. This does not (yet) answer the question